# Disable Application Insights Telemetry dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track calls in production environment for asp.net mvc app

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, azure-application-insights

I want to disable application insights telemetry calls in production for asp.net web mvc app, specifically dc.services.visualstudio.com/v2/track calls. I already tried disabling it by

`TelemetryConfiguration.Active.DisableTelemetry = true;`

and removing InstrumentationKey
but track calls are not stopping in production environment.

How to disable track calls without removing Application Insights from Application for particular environment ?

Below is the request from browser(chrome) :

[image]

Comment: it's a .net core or .net framework project? By disabling, you mean not send the request and no data is sent to application insights?

Comment: it is .net framework project.

Comment: @user1672994..This is for .net core application. We have .net web application

Comment: @ctor where do you add `xxx.DisableTelemetry = true`?

Comment: Do you also have [Client Side](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/asp-net#add-client-side-monitoring) enabled? I am asking because your browser is sending those requests.

Comment: @krig...You are right. We had client side script responsible for track calls. Thank you.